# Bonneville Salt Flats - access?

Tags: usa, driving, utah

There doesn't seem to be a Wikitravel page on this, and the Salt Lake City page doesn't mention them.

I'm wondering about visiting the Bonneville Salt Flats, and whether there's public access to drive on them, and whether you can do so with a rental car?

I've found a yahoo answers comment, but I'd really want something more authorative to accept as an answer...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's all highly regulated since years ago, though I probably get this from watching *The World's Fastest Indian*.

Comment: As to rental cars, read your rental agreement carefully: there's a good chance that it forbids driving the car off paved public roads.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### [Bonneville Salt Flats FAQs](http://www.blm.gov/pgdata/etc/medialib/blm/ut/salt_lake_fo/bonneville_salt_flats/pdfs.Par.43019.File.dat/Bonneville%20Salt%20Flats%20FAQ.pdf)

> **When is it open to the public?** The Bonneville Salt Flats are free and open to the
>   public most of the year. During landspeed racing events and/or filming projects, special
>   security restrictions may be required to maintain public safety. See below for details.
>   If you go out onto the salt flats on your own, let someone know where you are and when
>   you plan to return. Getting stuck out alone on the flats is dangerous and has resulted in
>   past fatalities. If you do decide to travel off the access road, please review and adhere to
>   the attached BSF Travel Advisory.

Also:

> **What facilities are available?** Toilets, food, beverages, and souvenirs are available at most
>   recreation events. At all other times of the year, there are no
>   facilities available at Bonneville. Once you go from the access road
>   onto the salt flats, there are no surface improvements or signs. You
>   are on your own. Food, fuel, lodging, and other services are available
>   at the freeway exit truck stop or in the nearby town of Wendover.

And:

> **How do I get there?** The Bonneville Salt Flats are located just off of
>   Exit 4 on Interstate 80 in Utah, just before reaching the Nevada state
>   line. They are approximately 100 miles and 1.5 hours driving time due
>   west of Salt Lake City. After exiting the freeway, turn right and
>   drive north past the truck stop. Stay on the paved road as it curves
>   to the right away from the mountains and heads east out across the mud
>   flats. In just over 4 miles, you will come to a cul-de-sac at the end
>   of the pavement where a BLM sign is located. You may park here or
>   continue onto the Salt Flats.

Comment: It seems Mark's questions are asked with some frequency (-:

Answer (score 1):

I visited the flats today, and apparently, other than the wet, public, watered area a couple inches deep, most of the dry flats I found were privately owned. I don't know if this is true for all of the flats, but you would have to do some research on public and private salt flat areas. Hope this provides some background info for you. If it doesn't hope you find what you're looking for.